# What is the usage of SAML LogoutRequest when SLO profile is not enabled?

Tags: single-sign-on, logout, saml

"LogoutRequest" is mentioned in SAML Core (saml-core-2.0-os:3.7.1) and SAML Profiles (saml-profiles-2.0-os:4.4.3.1) specifications under Single Logout (SLO). A "sessionIndex" is needed for SLO to work, otherwise there's no way to map the session participants. However, sessionIndex is an optional element according to the core specification. So, it implies LogoutRequests can be sent even when SLO profile is not enabled/supported.

Yes, I'm aware SAML can be used for many security usecases - not only SSO. But, in a SAML SSO scenario, if SLO is not enabled, it seems just sending any request (other than a SAML LogoutRequest) to Identity Provider (IdP) logout endpoint should be sufficient to invalidate this single session. If I recall correctly SalesForce and GoogleApps do just that.

Involving a SAML LogoutRequest in such a scenario seems to be a waste of processing. One can argue using signed LogoutRequests will make sure that the request is sent by a trusted party, but in reality a cyber-criminal will only want to login - not logout.

However, some SAML SSO Providers support LogoutRequests in a non-SLO scenario. What would be the usefulness of this?

Answer (score 0):

If SLO is done using redirect then it could be argued that the LogoutRequest would not be needed, but it is a good practice to establish that the SLO request was sent by a trused party using the signature. Its a bad idea to allow actions from parties you dont trust if you dont need to.

In the case that synchronous SOAP is used for SLO. The request is needed to identify the session with sessionindex.

> However, some SAML SSO Providers support LogoutRequests in a non-SLO scenario. What would be the usefulness of this?

With this do you mean that the providers issues the session index attribute? The session index is not only used for SLO request but also for AuthnQuery. But I think most providers include this just because they support SLO and generate this sessionindex by default. Even if the receiving party does not use it.